# How can i transform Sql code to codeigniter syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
select
    x1.category
    , x1.title
from yourtable x1
where
    (
    select count(*)
    from yourtable x2
    where x2.category = x1.category
    and x2.title <= x1.title
    ) <= 2
order by category, title;
```

I have something like this in my Model.

```
$this->db->select('x1.category','x1.title, false);
         $this->db->from('yourtable as x1');
         $sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('where');
         $sub ->select('count(*) ')<=25;
         $sub ->from('yourtable as x2');
         $sub ->where('x2.category = x1.category and x2.title<= x1.title');
         $this->subquery->end_subquery('count(*)'); 
        $this->db->order_by('category','title','RANDOM');
        $query = $this->db->get('yourtable');
```

And i received error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function start_subquery() on a non-object in ....

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup subqueries for codeigniter:

http://labs.nticompassinc.com/CodeIgniter-Subqueries/

Additionally, you can just do:

```
$this->db->select('x1.category','x1.title', false);
$this->db->from('yourtable as x1');
$this->db->where('(SELECT count(*) FROM yourtable x2 WHERE x2.category = x1.category AND x2.title <= x1.title) <= 2', NULL, false);
$this->db->order_by('category','title');
```